# in normal mode, How to place the cursor at the end of the line just like how insert mode behaves?

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-movement, normal-mode, cursor

Is there a way to set the cursor in normal mode to the end of the line?
for example, `|abcdefg` to `abcdefg|` not `abcdef|g`

[Cursor moves one character backwards on exiting insert mode](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3138/cursor-moves-one-character-backwards-on-exiting-insert-mode)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21447058/how-to-move-vim-cursor-actually-to-the-end-of-line-word

I looked up these but these threads don't give the solution to the problem but rather explaining how the default behavior of vim works.

Is there a way to move cursor at the end of the line just like how insert mode does with appending?

Comment: possible duplicate https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14451/move-cursor-to-new-line-character/14454#14454

Comment: For inserting text at the end, `A` is better than `$a` or `g$i`. If you can say more about why you want the cursor in that position, we can suggest better ideas.

Comment: thanks for the comment Ben. you're right, sorry for the inconvenience. as I use both vim/vscode I wanted the editors to look same to avoid the confusion, using a vertical bar rather than a block and locate the cursor at the beginning of the character in all modes rather than how vim originally behaves, and this resulted me to ask this question. for now, I'm happy with what Mass answered. using ```virtualedit=onemore```, re-mapping ```$``` to ```g$``` and also ```i``` to ```a```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but only if `virtualedit=onemore` or `virtualedit=all`.

If these options are enabled, then you can go to "one past the end of the line" using `g$`.